# Bring up PostgreSQL 13 cluster with Patroni and enabling scram-sha-256

Tags: postgresql, patroni

I am trying to bring up a PG13 cluster via patroni along with "scram-sha-256" password_encryption. Besides, I have changed the default md5 to scram-sha-256 in pg_hba.conf as well. However, once patroni was trying to bring the instance up, it complained error like below:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

And from postgresql log file:

```
2022-04-07 06:35:49.218 GMT [5212]: [2-1] db=[unknown], user=[unknown], app=[unknown], client=::1LOCATION:  BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:4409
2022-04-07 06:35:49.229 GMT [5212]: [3-1] db=postgres, user=postgres, app=[unknown], client=::1FATAL:  28P01: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2022-04-07 06:35:49.229 GMT [5212]: [4-1] db=postgres, user=postgres, app=[unknown], client=::1DETAIL:  User "postgres" does not have a valid SCRAM secret.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 5: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256"
2022-04-07 06:35:49.229 GMT [5212]: [5-1] db=postgres, user=postgres, app=[unknown], client=::1LOCATION:  auth_failed, auth.c:334
```

May I know if there is anything I missed?

Comment: The password hash for the user is not stored in a format which can be used with scram.  Set password_encryption appropriately, then change the password so that it gets stored into the correct format.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes for your reply, I have fixed the issue by modifying the pg_hba.conf, now it is working.